# Why doesn't Excel get to 0?

Tags: microsoft-excel

If you sequentially subtract a number from row to row, sometimes excel will get close to, but not 0, even though 0 is the right answer?  For example, if you start out with 1 and subtract 0.05 sequentially from the previous answer, you should eventually get to 0, but excel does not.  Sometimes this poses a problem in doing financial calculations.  Is there a setting that will convert these numbers to exact 0?  I am reluctant to use round() in that it may adversely impact the other numbers that I would like to have the appropriate level of precision.

Comment: Try setting the cell formats to **Number**, **Currency** or **Accounting** and set an appropriate number of decimal places

Comment: The problem is that .05 in a decimal expression of the value 5 hundreths. However, the computer has to work in binary, and the binary representation of the value is an irrational number with no exact representation... like trying to express 1/3 as a decimal. This leads to small inaccuracies and rounding errors in the math.

Comment: Thanks James.  I think that will optically make the number look right.  However, I think the value still remains and is used in subsequent calculations.

Comment: Don't be afraid of using ROUND! All financial institutions that use computers face this same problem and also must make a decision about how much precision that *actually* need.